# Enabling ElasticSearch RestClient response logging when using elastic4s and logback

Tags: elasticsearch, logback, apache-commons-logging, elastic4s

I am using [`elastic4s` v6.5.2](https://github.com/sksamuel/elastic4s/tree/v6.5.2) to send pretty simple index/update requests to ElasticSearch.
`elastic4s` uses `com.elasticsearch.client.RestClient` under the hood, which [seems to support response logging](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v6.5.2/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.java#L535).
My goal is to incorporate these logs in my application (write them to a file/stdout).

In my project, I am using [`logback`](http://logback.qos.ch/index.html) as the logging framework, whereas elasticsearch (and subsequently its `RestClient`) uses [`commons-logging`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/index.html), as far as I understand.

I have tried:

- Adding a new `<logger>` in my logback configuration
  (both for the package `name="org.elasticsearch.client` and the specific class `name="org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient"`)
- Adding a `commons-logging.properties` file into my project's resources with any of these:

  `.level=trace`
  `org.elasticsearch.client.level=trace`
  `org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.level=trace`

I have also tried different log levels - `fine`, `trace`, `all`.

None of these helped - elasticsearch's `logger.isDebugEnabled()` method always returns `false`.
Internally, elasticsearch's `RequestLogger` has a `Jdk14Logger` (from `commons-logging`) and calls its `isDebugEnabled()` method, which in turn has a `java.util.logging.Logger` and calls its `isLoggable(Level.FINE)` method which returns `false`, since it has no logging level defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to solving this was removing the `commons-logging` dependency and instead adding a dependency on `jcl-over-slf4j`.
In `sbt` this would look like this:

```scala
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "jcl-over-slf4j" % "1.7.25"
excludeDependencies += "commons-logging" % "commons-logging"
```

After this, the logger can be configured with `logback` as simply as:

```xml
<logger name="org.elasticsearch.client" level="debug"/>
```